# GDM configuration on Solaris 11?

Tags: solaris, solaris-11

On Solaris 10 it was located in `/etc/X11/gdm/gdm.conf` but that file is missing from a standard Solaris 11 install. When I run the command `slocate gdm.conf` the only file I get is `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/gdm.conf` which I don't this is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

found with

```
find / |grep gdm
```

It's in `/etc/gdm`. for xdmcp it should suffice to write `enable=true` under `[xdmcp]` in `custom.conf`.